# Spring security csrf not working with spring-session

Tags: spring-security, spring-session

I'm using spring-session version 1.0.0.M1 and I have configured it to use the `MapSessionRepository`:
        sessionFilterChainReg.addMappingForServletNames(EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST), false, dispatcherServletReg.getName());

```
@Bean(name = {"defaultSessionFilter", "sessionFilter"})
public SessionRepositoryFilter sessionFilter() {
    return new SessionRepositoryFilter((SessionRepository) applicationContext.getBean("sessionRepository"));
}


@Bean(name = { "defaultSessionRepository", "sessionRepository" })
public SessionRepository defaultSessionRepository() {
    return new MapSessionRepository();
}
```

and then in the web-config:

```
    final FilterRegistration sessionFilterChainReg = servletContext.addFilter("sessionFilter", DelegatingFilterProxy.class);
```

So I have in my register.jsp the following input hidden element:

```
<input type="hidden" id="${_csrf.parameterName}" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
```

And I can see the page gets rendered with a correct CSRF token. When I submit the POST request the CSRF filter is triggered and the token is passed correctly to the filter, which calls the `HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository:loadToken` and in there on line 66 we see:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
```

and now the session is null, so the repository returns a null CSRF token and then a `MissingCsrfTokenException` is thrown. Is there something else I need to configure?

Here's the stacktrace when hitting line 66 (there's a lot more, but i guess this is the relevant part of it):

```
at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository.loadToken(HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository.java:66)
  at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:75)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
  at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
  at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
  at org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:144)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1632)
  at org.springframework.session.web.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:83)
  at org.springframework.session.web.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:66)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1632)
```

Comment: CSRF support does not create a session until you prepare a view that contains the CSRF token in it. Where are you using the CSRF token? You need a view (i.e. JSP, Thymeleaf template, response header, etc) that contains the CSRF token in it. Another thing to try is does it work w/out Spring Session?

Comment: Hi Rob, I updated the question. Yes, it works perfectly well without spring session and the CSRF token is passed correctly to the filter, but the session returned on HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository:loadToken:66 is null.

Comment: Can you look at the request to see what cookies are present? It may be related to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/34 If you see multiple session cookies, you should delete all of them and then try again.

Comment: Hi Rob, I had a lot of cookies (about 35) with just only 1 called SESSION. I deleted all the cookies and tried again, but the result is the same - i get MissingCsrfTokenException. Also I just noticed that not-only the register form doesn't work, but also the login form is broken now - exactly the same problem.

Comment: Can you copy/paste the call stack to the post from your IDE when you add a debug point to HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository:loadToken:66?

Comment: Hi Rob, I have pasted it in the question.

Comment: At this point everything looks correct to me. Is there anyway you can create a small sample project that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem - I myself was having a `Filter` which Wrapped the `HttpServletRequest` object and the filter was firing before the `SessionRepositoryFilter`. I'm not sure this is correct but to force it to fire after the `SessionRepositoryFilter` I did this:

```
@Bean(name = {"defaultSessionFilter", "sessionFilter"})
public Filter sessionFilter() {
    CompositeFilter compositeFilter = new CompositeFilter();
    compositeFilter.setFilters(Arrays.asList(new SessionRepositoryFilter((SessionRepository) applicationContext.getBean("sessionRepository")), applicationContext.getBean("myFilter")));

    return compositeFilter;
}
```

which solves the problem.